# Importing BigQuery on Pycharm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, pycharm

I've been trying to import bigQuery on PyCharm and it doesn't work.
There's always a red underline on bigQuery though I have installed all the necessary packages.
The error message I'm getting is

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "~~~\write_csv.py", line 1, in 
from google.cloud import bigquery
ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

Is it related to firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Probably `google-cloud-bigquery` package is not installed.

Try this command in terminal: `pip instal google-cloud-bigquery`.

Official docs - https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html#installation